# Convert array into key / value pairs

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I have pushed different values from nested loops into an object, resulting in something like this:

```
obj = ["blue", 1, "red", 4, "yellow", 2, "green", 7];
```

But I'd like it to return like this:

```
obj = [{"blue": 1}, {"red": 4}, {"yellow": 2}, {"green": 7}];
```

Do I have to manually build that syntax or is there a quicker way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a simple for loop.

```js
var obj = ["blue", 1, "red", 4, "yellow", 2, "green", 7];

var res = [];

for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i += 2) {
  var o = {};
  o[obj[i]] = obj[i + 1];
  res.push(o);
}

console.log(res);
```

---

An ES6 solution using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) method.

```js
let obj = ["blue", 1, "red", 4, "yellow", 2, "green", 7];

console.log(Array.from({ length: obj.length / 2 }, (_, i) => ({ [obj[2 * i]]: obj[2 * i + 1] })));
```

Answer (score 2):

Make use of a for loop to acieve the result like

```js
var obj = ["blue", 1, "red", 4, "yellow", 2, "green", 7];

var newObj = []
for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i+=2) {
  var temp = {};
  temp[obj[i]] = obj[i + 1];
  newObj.push(temp);
  
}
console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
var obj = ["blue", 1, "red", 4, "yellow", 2, "green", 7];
  var newObj = [];
  var itemValue,itemName = '';
  $(obj).each(function(index, item){
    if(index % 2 == 0){
      if(itemName != ''){
        var newObjEle = {};
        newObjEle[itemName] = itemValue;
        newObj.push(newObjEle);
      }
      itemName = item;
    }
    else{
        itemValue = item
    }
  })
  console.log(newObj);
```

[**Working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/hmt3q3o3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to initialize the result with an array of empty JSON objects, and then iterate through it to populate the objects.

```js
var obj = ["blue", 1, "red", 4, "yellow", 2, "green", 7];

var result = Array.apply(null, Array(obj.length / 2)).map(i => ({}));
result.forEach((c, i, a) => (a[i][obj[2 * i]] = obj[2 * i + 1]));

console.log(result);
```